# Get the width of screen when in portrait mode

Tags: android

I want to get the width of the screen in portrait mode. This code

```
public static int getScreenWidth() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }
```

gives me the full width and what I want is just the width visible to the user (the width of the phone's screen not the complete resolution).

Comment: What is the difference between "the width of the phone's screen not the complete resolution"? Can you give a specific example of where those are not the same thing? This would help us understand what it is that you are seeking.

Comment: On the phone i'm using, when I use the above code, places the item far away (where it's invisible to me). But when I place the item at 200 along the X-axis, It appears around half of the screen.

Comment: i think the width that code gives me is 1080.

Comment: You are probably using `dp`, not pixels. `dp` is a logical unit, not physical. Use `px` to specify distance in actual pixels.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on you comment the problem is when you position a view using `getScreenWidth()`, the view doesn't appear.

When you position a view, distance between left screen edge and **left view edge** is set. Please, take a look at this image:

[image]

Code below takes `View` object and positions it next to the right screen edge.

```
public void alignViewRight(View v) {
    v.setX(getScreenWidth() - v.getWidth());
}

public int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}
```